# Conditional rollup fields for report

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I have a report requirement to calculate campaign revenue (sum of associated Opportunity's actual revenue) on the basis of 30 days old, 60 days old and 90 days old opportunity. We are working on Dynamics crm online 2015.

Something like the following:

---

Campaign  30Days-Opp-Rev 60Days-Opp-Rev 90Days-Opp-Rev

---

What I have done so far:
1- I have tried to create rollup fields on campaign, but they don't allow conditions to restrict summation of opp revenue on the basis of date.
2- I have tried calculated fields but they don't summing up of child fields.
3- I have tried FetchXML reports but it doesn't support subquery or UNION types in xml.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can write c# plugin and execute your fetch query in your plugin